# Insert break / sleep after showing a hidden button

Tags: ios, swift, hidden, viewcontroller, break

I want to make a button appear, then I want to show it for 1 second and after that the view controller has to change.
I tried my best. but it doesn't matter where I put the sleep(1); - it always does the same. It waits for 1 second, then displays the button for a very very short time and changes to the other view controller.

Can anyone help?

My code:

```
[self.resultButton setTitle:category forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.resultButton.hidden = NO;

sleep(1);

UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapViewControllerID"];

[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `swift` when you're clearly using objective-c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GCD's `dispatch_after` to accomplish this.

```
[self.resultButton setTitle:category forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.resultButton.hidden = NO;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapViewControllerID"];
  [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
});
```

---

You should also note that the view controller assignment that you've written creates a default `UIViewController` and then immediately throws that object away and assigns a view controller from your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use NSTimer to call a specific function after a period of delay and in that function put the code to show new view controller

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector:  Selector("showController"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func showController(){

    //present view controller here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `dispatch_after()` like it is being described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/1545323)

Comment: @ian-macdonald answer was faster and more accurate.